# How to fix libpng warning when reading interlaced PNG?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, windows-7, libpng

I am using OpenCV with Visual Studio 2010 to read and display some images(including jpg and png). My program is working fine but sometimes it fails with the following warning :

```
libpng warning: interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image.
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (failed to allocate 1398604 bytes) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52
```

I tried searching on the internet for the fix but couldn't get any. Any help regarding the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
number_passes = png_set_interlace_handling(png_ptr);
```

at the appropriate place in the calling application,
just after

```
png_get_IHDR();
```

If you don't want to rebuild the calling application,
a workaround is to use an application such as ImageMagick's "convert"
to de-interlace the PNG before you try to read it with your application:

```
convert in.png -interlace none out.png
```